# Vim search across directories for a file or directory

Tags: vim, markdown

I am using Vim to create Markdown files. For relative links like:

`- [Configure AWS with Role Credentials](/group/product/latest/operations/cloud-providers/configure-aws-cloud-provider-roles)`

I'd like to be able to check for the directory/file in the link and see if it exists across a range of directories.

I was wanting to use something like:

`:vim 'word' **./*.md | copen`

which is what i use to find words/phrases across directories. Is there a way to do something like this, from the Vim command line?

Answer (score 2):

For searching, a lot of Vim users install libraries like Ack, The Silver Searcher (AKA `Ag`), or RipGrep (AKA `Rg`). These can be run via the command line or with library-specific Vim plugins.

If searching the word with vanilla Vim is your goal, you could use `:grep` or `:vimgrep`. Enter command mode with `shift` + `:`, and then search:

```
:grep word **/*.md
```

Where `word` is your word and `**/*.md` is the directory where your markdown files are stored. Adjust the asterisks to include more directories.

Matches would be available in the Quickfix List, which you can see with `:cw`, also command mode.

`:vimgrep` and `:grep` are powerful; check out `:help :vimgrep` and `:help :grep` to learn more.

Comment: Can i use this method to find a specific file/directory in a specific directory path? It is this relative directory I was really trying to look for in an elegant Vim manner.

Comment: @RussUrquhart the match pattern should work with any pattern you give it. Do you have an directory structure in mind, that I could demonstrate in the answer?

Comment: Something like this path:

`/group/product/latest/operations/cloud-providers/configure-aws-cloud-provider-roles`

I need to check if this directory path exists.

Comment: @RussUrquhart Is your goal is to find a markdown file, or files, in that directory? If so, replace `**/*.md` in my example with `/group/product/latest/operations/cloud-providers/configure-aws-cloud-provider-roles/*.md`,

Comment: Yes, I'm just looking to make sure there is an index.md file, in that directory. Question, do I NEED to have a `word` parameter? Just looking for the existence of the file, at that location?

Comment: @RussUrquhart ah, ok. You just want to know if a linked file exists? Could you try `gf` (goto file) with your cursor over the file name you're linking to in the markdown?